# extracting values from laser scan data!

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have three objects in front of my robot. I want to specify distance to these objects. i have converted pointcloud into laser scan. now i want to extract the least values from the laser scan data. it seems it provides data from the environment as well. how can i access to the values for instance less than 10 in my laser scan data??

thanks

[image: image description]

ranges: [19.067832946777344, inf, inf, inf, inf, 6.741373538970947, 6.757254123687744, 6.757254123687744, 6.773134708404541, 6.773135185241699, 6.794971466064453, 6.791001319885254, 6.7870306968688965, 6.785045623779297, 6.785045623779297, 6.7691650390625, 6.743358612060547, 6.691746234893799, 6.6679253578186035, 6.7413740158081055, 6.9517927169799805, 7.049062252044678, 7.2495574951171875, 7.410350322723389, 7.428215503692627, 7.634665489196777, 7.819278240203857, 7.952279567718506, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 11.731189727783203, 11.695326805114746, 11.687356948852539, 11.683372497558594, 11.711265563964844, 11.755098342895508, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 19.015905380249023, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 6.43577766418457, 6.289599895477295, 6.252068042755127, 6.175027847290039, 5.9537858963012695, 5.901679515838623]
intensities: []

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404693/extracting-values-from-laser-scan-data!/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> i have converted pointcloud into laser scan....

From you question, I am guessing that you are using [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) package. If not, then you can consider using it. Because it does exactly what you are looking for.

> how can i access to the values for instance less than 10 in my laser scan data??

"less than 10", I assume the unit is in meters. In you are using the `depthimage_to_laserscan` package, you should set the `~range_max` parameter. Surprisingly, the default value is 10 meters. I suggest you check out the wiki page for more information.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-08**:
@Ravi Joshi
thanks, i received the point cloud from 3d lidar. and i used pointcloud_to_laserscan package. as i checked depthimage_to_laserscan, it is for melodic and noetic. i am working with kinetic 16.04.

I have converted pointcloud from 3d lidar, to laserscan. i just wanted to extract the first three minimum values (as i have three objects infront of my robot).

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-08**:
How about sorting the received scan, say `ranges` attribute in `sensor_msgs/LaserScan.msg`, and then take the first 3 values? Of course, this assumes that there is only one point on every object, which is not a correct approach. But please check your LaserScan.msg by plotting it. You may apply clustering to get 3 clusters (instead of 3 points). BTW, do not forget to set `~range_min` and `~range_max` in `pointcloud_to_laserscan_node`.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-08**:
@Ravi Joshi ,
sorry, is there any way to first remove/or filter the environment noise from the point cloud, and then convert the point cloud to the laser scan data?
becasue when i convert the pointcloud into laser scan, it provides me the ranges of the points that are too far from the robot and relate to the environment, if i could remove them it was good.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-08**:
I am having difficulty understanding the problem correctly. When you say "that are too far from the robot", I wonder why don't you set `~range_max` param in the first place.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-08**:
Dear @Ravi Joshi
I know what you are mening. i have set the range_max = 10 , but as you can see in the attached image, in the right side top, those points are showing to me. i donot want them. i want the points in the middle.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-08**:
@Ravi Joshi Thanks a lot for your support.
The issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are subscribing to the laser scan topic (which I am assuming you are) can access the values for the distances using:

> message.ranges

which contains all distance values from  **message.angle_min** to **message.angle_max** with a **message.angle_increment** incremental step.

let's say you want the distance in the exact center of the array then use the **len(message.ranges)** to get the total number of scan beams and extract the center **message.ranges[center_index].**

You may want to use a range of angles (one angle is not reliable) like **message.ranges[50:70]** then extract the minimum value in that range and use it as a reference for your distance calculation logic.

---

Originally posted by [Ammar Albakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/106635/ammar-albakri/) with karma: 31 on 2022-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check the `laser_filters` package from there:

- https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_filters/tree/kinetic-devel
- ros.org/wiki/laser_filters

> Assorted filters designed to
> operate on 2D planar laser scanners,
> which use the sensor_msgs/LaserScan type.

There is an old branch for Kinetic. Worth a try.

The Wiki has a lot of examples too. Especially **4.5 LaserScanRangeFilter** seems suitable for your case.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-08**:
@ljaniec
Thanks